# Proving Generalized CLT for Stable Distributions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

Let $0<a\le 2$.

> $(*)$ If $X_i$ are nonnegative iid RVs and  $S_n=X_1+\cdots + X_n$ with $$S_n/n^{1/a} \to X$$
>    in distribution, where $X$ is **stable symmetric**, then $P(X_1>x)=x^{-a}L(x)$ with $L$ slowly varying (so that $\lim _{x\to \infty}\frac{L(mx)}{L(x)}=1 \,\, \forall m>0$).

Theorem 3.7.2 of https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE4_1.pdf proves something stronger than the converse. I tried mimicking this proof and similar proofs of the converse statement in hopes of proving $(*)$ but I haven't had any luck.

How can one show $(*)$? For simplicity I tried also consdiering the case that $X$ has characteristic function $e^{-c|t|^a}.$